# Update case class data in an array

Tags: scala, case-class

I am trying to update case class from an array.
Trying to update case class data inside an array, but I have to remove older record as well

I have tried as below

```
case class Data(str1: String, str2:String) { def updateMsg(msg : String) = this.copy(str2 = msg)}
val list = Array(Data("1", "2"), Data("2", "b"), Data("3", "c"))
list :+ list.filter(_.str1.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))(0).updateMsg("a")
```

I got results from above list as below

```
Array[Data] = Array(Data(1,2), Data(2,b), Data(3,c), Data(1,a))
```

Is there any better way to update existing case class row ?

Comment: @TomerShetah :1. Whenever I do an update in case class data I have to update the existing row [But In my case instead of updating row I am creating a new row with updated values]. 2. I am using `scala 2.11` version, could please suggest me instead `array` what will I have to use.

Comment: I would recommend you to use **Lists** or any other concrete immutable collection, instead of plain **Arrays**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `map` should do it:

```
list.map { data =>
  if (data.str1.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
    data.updateMsg("a")
  } else {
    data
  }
}
```

or

```
list.map {
  case data if data.str1.equalsIgnoreCase("1") =>
    data.updateMsg("a")
  case data =>
    data
}
```